# Find string between two strings in jQuery

Tags: jquery, regex

I have a static Google Map like this:

```
<img alt="Map" height="135" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?scale=2&amp;center=45.504358%2C-73.553712&amp;language=en&amp;zoom=15&amp;markers=scale%3A2%7Cshadow%3Afalse%7Cicon%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fyelp-images.s3.amazonaws.com%2Fassets%2Fmap-markers%2Fannotation_64x86.png%7C45.504358%2C-73.553712&amp;client=gme-yelp&amp;sensor=false&amp;size=286x135&amp;signature=nM1FwS0L3z_VgK2ljaRcJf11HxA=" width="286">
```

How it is possible to get just the part in a variable

```
var lat = 45.504358;
var lng = -73.553712;
```

I tried:

```
var mapSrc = $(pageDetails).find('[alt="Map"]').prop('src');
var card_Latitude = mapSrc.match(/center=(.*?)%2C-/i)[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a generic function for grabbing query string parameters with JS (see this answer):

[How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

So it's just like this:

```
function getParameterByName(name, url) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

Then in your particular case you just call it like this (assuming your img is named "img"):

```
var center = getParameterByName("center",document.getElementById("img").src).split(",");

alert("lat: " + center[0] + " long: " + center[1]);
```

See this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/soemdjah/1

Answer (score 0):

```
center=(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)%2C(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/iO1uK1/9

Comment: How can I change my code to include your idea please ? When I replace it, it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use base javascript RegExp :

```
var matches = new RegExp('center=(\\d+\\.?\\d*)%2C(-?\\d+\\.?\\d*)').exec(mapSrc);
if (matches) {
    var lat = matches[1];
    var lng = matches[2];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split your `src` by parameters and then split by key / value pair of each parameter in order to find the `latitude` and `logitude` value within the src property. Eg:

```
var mapSrc = $(pageDetails).find('[alt="Map"]').prop('src');
jQuery(mapSrc.split("&"), function(index, value) {
  var keyPair = value.split("=");
  if (keyPair[0] == "center") {
    var lat = decodeURIComponent(keyPair[1]).split(",")[0];
    var lng = decodeURIComponent(keyPair[1]).split(",")[1]
  }
});
```

Using above, no regex is needed at all. However, if you want to still use `regex` for this task, here is the pattern: `'center=([^%]+)%2C-([^&]+)'`

Answer (score 0):

One more solution:

```
;center=( [.\d]+)%?[0-9A-Z]+([-.\d+]+)
```

*Demo*
http://regex101.com/r/qK0jJ1/2